# Accessing a static variablefrom a class instance

Tags: php

I would like to use this line of code:

```
$this->ClassInstance::$StaticVariable;
```

Where this is the basic setup:

```
Class foo{
   public static $StaticVariable;
}

$this->ClassInstance = new foo();
```

What is the reasoning behind this being a parse error?

When this:

```
$ClassInstance = $this->ClassInstance;
$ClassInstance::$StaticVariable;
```

Is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant

```
Class Foo{
    public static $StaticVariable = 42;
}

class Bar {
    private $ClassInstance;

    public function fn() {
        $this->ClassInstance = new Foo();
        return $this->ClassInstance::$StaticVariable;
    }
}

$bar = new Bar;
echo $bar->fn();
```

Then [this works as of PHP7](https://3v4l.org/GabDR). Prior to that, the parser could simply not dereference this. See the [wiki page linked in the comments to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705845/accessing-a-static-variablefrom-a-class-instance#comment72533627_42705845) for details.

You could use `get_class($this->ClassInstance)::$StaticVariable;` though.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP docs

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).

source http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 2):

You can access it with `self::$staticVariable` or `foo::$staticVariable`. No need to make use of the instance.